# How to get a color of a web element using Selenium WebDriver with python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

How do I locate the background-color of a webelement in hexadecimal format? With my current selenium webdriver python code it is returning the background-color in RGB format.

**This is the html element that I am looking at**

```
div class="bar" style="background-color: #DD514C; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EE5F5B, #C43C35); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , #EE5F5B, #C43C35); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top , #EE5F5B, #C43C35); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#EE5F5B, endColorstr=#C43C35, GradientType=0); background-repeat: repeat-x; color: #ffffff; width: 11.5%"
```

**My webdriver python code is:**

```
find_element_by_class_name("bar").get_attribute("style")
```

It is returning the style with the colors in rgb format. I want to specifically get the background-color in hexadecimal format so that I can compare it with my expected value. I am getting the following output now:

```
background-color: rgb(221, 81, 76); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(238, 95, 91), rgb(196, 60, 53)); background-repeat: repeat-x; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 11.5%;
```

Comment: I found a lot of solutions using getCssValue for Java? What is the python equivalent of getCssValue?

Comment: The python equivalent is element.value_of_css_property('background-color').  But it doesn't return hexadecimal (the Java doesn't either: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java).  unutbu's answer will give you hexadecimal.

Comment: Can anyone help me by telling how can i change this{RGB} value using python

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for `value_of_css_property('background-color')`:

```
rgb = find_element_by_class_name("bar").value_of_css_property('background-color')
```

However, this will return the string `rgb(221, 81, 76)`. In order to get the hex value of it, you can use @unutbu's answer:

```
import re
...
rgb = find_element_by_class_name("bar").value_of_css_property('background-color')

r,g,b = map(int, re.search(
             r'rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)', rgb).groups())
color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)
```

And your hex `color` is the string `#dd514c`.

Comment: Simpler color conversion is shared here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49827874/248616

Answer (score 8):

To convert color, you can directly use selenium's Color class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color

rgb = find_element_by_class_name("bar").value_of_css_property('background-color')
hex = Color.from_string(rgb).hex
```

[Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.color.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

# style = find_element_by_class_name("bar").get_attribute("style")

style = 'background-color: rgb(221, 81, 76); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(238, 95, 91), rgb(196, 60, 53)); background-repeat: repeat-x; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 11.5%;'

r,g,b = map(int, re.search(
    r'background-color: rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)', style).groups())
print('{:X}{:X}{:X}'.format(r, g, b))
```

yields

```
DD514C
```

Answer (score 2):

As the format of the return matches a tuple this is achievable without using 're' where the return is an 'rgba' string:

```
import ast

rgba = element.value_of_css_property("background-color")
r, g, b, alpha = ast.literal_eval(rgba.strip("rgba"))
hex_value = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)
return hex_value, alpha
```

Where the string is 'rgb' simply omit the "alpha"

```
import ast

rgb = element.value_of_css_property("background-color")
r, g, b = ast.literal_eval(rgb.strip("rgb"))
hex_value = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)
return hex_value
```

Since the Original question was raised the preferred method is now to use selenium color support module:

A simple guide is [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.color)