# How to determine the size of html table in pixels given an html file

Tags: python, node.js

I have a html file that has various html tags in it. This html also has a bunch of tables in it. I am processing this file using python. How do I find out what the size (length x width in pixels) when it is rendered by a browser (preferably chrome or firefox)?

I am essentially looking for the information when you do "inspect element" on a browser, and you are able to see the size of the various elements. I want to access this size in my python code.

I am using lxml to parse my html and can use selenium if needed.

edit: added #node.js incase I can use it to spit out the size of all the tables in a shell script and I can grab it in python.

Comment: This depends on the browser, possibly the platform, the viewport size... E.g. the font rendering used will affect the advance of a string of text and thus potentially the width of a table. You pretty much have to actually render the page in a browser. If you're using Selenium, can't you just open the page with it and execute Javascript to determine the size?

Comment: @millimoose Yes, to address these, I had mentioned that I am OK with any browser, but preferred chrome/firefox. I also said that I want to access the size in my python code (I am aware that I can get the size using javascript)

Comment: Seeing as how no browsers actually support python scripting, and you have to use a real browser (via e.g. Selenium) to get a sane result, these requirements are contradictory. If you can drive Selenium from Python, you should also be able to tell the underlying browser to run some JS for you and return the result to the calling Python code.

Comment: `node.js` doesn't have any of the rendering code, so that's probably not going to help you.  It's just a javascript engine.

Comment: If you can call out to a shell script I'd just use PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) to open the HTML file in an actual browser installed on the computer that your Python code is running on.

I'm not sure how you'd use the Selenium WebDriver API to find out how tall a rendered table is, but [the `value_of_css_property` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117720/20578) might do it.

Comment: There's always [`JavascriptExecutor.executeScript()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) or whatever the Python equivalent is.

Comment: @millimoose: aha, that sounds more likely.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you can call out shellscript, **and** you can use Node.js, I'm assuming you could also install and use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a *headless* WebKit port. (I.e. an actual honest to goodness WebKit renderer that just doesn't require a window to work.) This will let you use Javascript and the familiar web libraries to manipulate the document. As an example, the following gets you the width of the logo element towards the upper left Stack Overflow site:

```
page = require('webpage').create(); // create a new "browser"

page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  // callback when loading completes
  var logoWidth = page.evaluate(function() {
    // This runs in the rendered page and uses the version of jQuery that SO loads.
    return $('#hlogo').width();
  });

  console.log(logoWidth); // prints 250, the same as Chrome.

  phantom.exit(); // for some reason you need to exit manually
});
```

The documentation for PhantomJS will tell you more about what you can do with it and how.

One caveat however is that loading a page takes a while, since it needs to fetch CSS and scripts and generally do everything a browser does. I'm not sure if and how PhantomJS does any caching, if it does it might make sense to reuse the same process for multiple scrapes of the same site.