# How to get pixels from a website quickly with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, pixel

I am making a program that will play a perfect snake game, but I need to tell the program when a snake reaches a certain space on the board so I can tell it to change directions. I haven't made any headway on this because I don't know where to start.

I am looking at https://www.google.com/fbx?fbx=snake_arcade where I want to know when the color changes for the box 17 across and 8 down on the grid so I know when the snake is there so I can keep it from running into the wall.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer). That might be better than screen reading

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am using selenium actually but I'm pretty new to it. Would it be better to switch to puppeteer or pyppeteer and if so what functions would I need to use?

Comment: You can use Selenium as well.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer what would I need to make Selenium do? Because so far I have just used it to open the browser and send the arrow keys. Can it also read pixels on the page? Is there a resource that would help me know what Selenium can do? (I haven't found it yet if there is one)

Comment: Sure you can get the color of elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102323/how-to-get-a-color-of-a-web-element-using-selenium-webdriver-with-python

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I probably should have made this more clear, but I am looking to read when the snake makes it to the square 17 across and 8 down at this website https://www.google.com/fbx?fbx=snake_arcade. I don't have a huge understanding, but I thought the grid as a whole was one element.

Answer (score 0):

getting a specific pixel from a website requires you to render it. Potentially this involves fetching additional resources or executing javascript.

One way to accomplish that is by using [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Once splash is set up you can get a screenshot of the rendered page. This screenshot you can access pixel wise.

It is not a pure python solution because you need to run a splash server. E.g. via docker. Actually it is not a python solution at all because the API just a HTTP API. However, you can use python to use it.

Comment: Is there a way to use python to take screenshots of the screen as a whole instead of the website and check for when certain pixels are not a certain color?

Comment: you find several solutions simply by googling "python screenshot" but keep in mind that the screen as a hole also involves the position of the browser window and other "noise".

Comment: I, therefore, recommend sticking to a screenshot of the website. Both splash and [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) (see commend of Maurice Meyer) are ways to accomplish that

Comment: I'm new to Selenium, is it able to compare screenshots of the website?

Comment: I'd say no. You can use it to get screenshots but analyzing them and detecting changes is a completely different task.