# Selenium python Expand and Collapse only if Button is Closed earlier

Tags: javascript, python, css, python-3.x, selenium

I have a website ,in which just wish to click and open a collapse/open window .My condition is only if this button was not open then open it otherwise proceed for next operation.
What is the response or key i need to add in selenium python code to do this operation.

May be this will help for more clarity.

Do not Click again this Box as it is already open
[image: Do not click as it is clicked]
[image: click and open as it is closed]

The X path of the particular button is
/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnv5l.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqv2d.png)/div/san/svg
and the code i used for click is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/san/svg').click()
```

All i want to do it ,if not previously this is clicked then only click,what parameter or option i need to use in selenium python to do this.

Adding More Details when the Box is Closed this is the "Elements code i see"

[image: Element code when Box in closed state]

When in Box open state this is the "element code" i get
[image: In Box open state]

Comment: after clicking it must have changed in html code part for that icon. You can write a try except for that. Inspect the element and check what changes has been .

Comment: @Pygirl Any code snippet example ?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49827874/6660373

Comment: @Pygirl the html code is added for both actions, could you help me with a code template,only if the box is in closed state by the selenium click and open else ignore this click step.Thank you

Comment: You have class widget pages which is initially hidden. You can use it. Selenium has a function which trigger the code when it founds the element. You can use it.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a mechanism to check if the box is open, there are a few ways to do this.

1. Check for the unique element that only exists within the box, such as the elements with `id` or `class` in the box. If they are present, the box is open and thus don't click again.
2. The first approach may not work for every website since some just use `hide` or similar class to hide the box. For these cases, check if the elements inside the box have the `hide` class, if they don't, the box is open and don't click it.
3. Check the button to see if it has a unique class/text for defining open and close, such as the colour of the button. From your photo, it turned blue after the box is open, maybe you can try to inspect if that's the case and use that as a way to check if the box is open.

Comment: i have added the html code in both action ,could you help me with a code template,only if the box is in closed state by the selenium click and open else ignore this click step.Thank you