# How to get text color using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to get the color of the text from each cell in 1 column table. The HTML for a single cell looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody>
      <tr>
           <td class="table-centerText"><font color="red">1</font> </td>
           <td class="table-centerText">22:06</td>
           <td class="table-centerText">10:17</td>
           <td class="table-centerText">55124</td>
           <td class="table-centerText">70.3</td>
           <td class="table-centerText">-35.2</td>
           <td> <a href="preview.php?datasetID=16709">View</a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My code to find the text color of each column looks like this:

```
pointing_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody")
table_rows = []
table_rows = pointing_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
num_rows = len(table_rows) - 1
print(num_rows)

for x in range(num_rows):
total = 0
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]" % (x + 2))
color = element.value_of_css_property("color")
print(color)
```

The loop does check the correct cell in each iteration, but the color is always "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" which is wrong because the text color changes and is never black. I tried replacing `color` with `background-color`, which returned the correct background color for each cell. Unfortunately, I need the text color. Replacing `color` with `font-color` or `text-color` doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like you may need to go into the `font` tag before grabbing the color attribute? Not certain though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this :

```
//table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]
```

to :

```
//table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/font
```

and get the color like this :

```
color = element.get_attribute("color")
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with css selectors. Just get `color` attribute:

```
color = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".table-centerText>font").get_attribute("color")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `.value_of_css_property()` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117720/248616), and color hex converted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49827874/248616)

```
argb = find_element_xx('some selector xx').value_of_css_property('color')
hex  = Color.from_string(argb).hex
```